# Create a circular plot in R that visualizes actions between minutes on a 60 minute clock

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a circular plot that represents a 60-minute clock with the color bars representing actions that occur at those times. I've managed to make a rudimentary version of it but am at a loss about how to proceed. Here is what I have thus far:
[image]

My goal is to make it so the 'Acoustic Sampling' bar is displayed between the 15 and 30 minute mark. 'Inactive1' be displayed between 0/60 and 15 minutes, 'Data Copy' between 36 and 40 minutes etc. The gist is to have each action fill the times they are supposed to occur in the data.

Also having all the 'Inactive' actions be part of the same group would be great, I can probably figure that out myself, I just need a pointer in the right direction. Don't want to be asking everyone to do everything for me.

Code:

```
attach(clock_data)
hsize <- 4

clock_data <- clock_data %>%
  mutate(x = hsize)

ggplot(clock_data, aes(x = hsize, y = Time, fill = Action)) +
  geom_col() + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  xlim(c(0.2, hsize + 0.5)) + theme_bw()
```

and the reprex for 'clock_data':

```
structure(list(Time_Between = c("0-15", "15-30", "30-33", "33-34", 
"34-35", "35-36", "36-40", "40-55", "55-56", "56-60"), Time = c(15L, 
15L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 15L, 1L, 4L), Action = c("Inactive1", 
"Acoustic Sampling", "Inactive2", "SSH Tunnel", "Inactive3", 
"Switch Pi", "Data Copy", "Data Transmission", "Switch Mini", 
"Inactive4"), x = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you do not account for the start and end of the intervals. One option to fix that would be separate `Time_between` into the start and end times, then use a `geom_rect` to create your bars instead of using a `geom_col`. Additionally I recoded the `Inactive`s as belonging to one group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

hsize <- 4

clock_data <- clock_data %>%
  mutate(x = hsize) %>%
  tidyr::separate(Time_Between,
    into = c("start", "end"),
    convert = TRUE
  ) |>
  mutate(
    Action = if_else(
      grepl("^Inactive", Action), "Inactive", Action
    ),
    # If needed: Reorder for the legend
    Action = reorder(Action, start, FUN = min)
  )

ggplot(clock_data) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = hsize - .45, ymin = start,
    xmax = hsize + .45, ymax = end,
    fill = Action
  )) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  xlim(c(0.2, hsize + 0.5)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: this is quite clever (+1)! I was able to get the things in the right order by turning them into a factor, but then wasn't able to get the legend right ‍ I could've sworn it was possible to separate out labelling from the data provided, but for the life of me I couldn't make it work

Comment: @Mark That's the second option. But you have to use two columns, i.e. the raw `Action` for the order which you could map on `group` and a recoded `Action` to map on `fill`.